# Using fs module in Meteor getting Uncaught TypeError _fs2.default.readFile is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, fs

Hi i am trying to test the fs module in my Meteor project. I am using Meteor 1.3 new es2015 modules. I'm trying to use nodes fs module to read a file. tried a few methods but seem to be getting this same error when i run myFunc() in browser.

Uncaught TypeError: _fs2.default.readFile is not a function

```
import fs from 'fs'


myFunc = function(){

    fs.readFile('input.txt', function(err, data){
        if(err)
            console.log("Error" + err)

        console.log("Data from input" + data)
    })

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't use `fs` module in the browser. There is a separate npm module for `fs` in the browser called [`fs-web`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-web). After installing this using `npm install fs-web --save`, you can use it by importing it in the client side files like this,

```
 import * as fs from 'fs-web';
```

Comment: Thanks didn't know that.